# Laravel request rules method validation switch case issue HTTP method

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, validation, switch-statement

I am developing a website with Laravel 5 and Angularjs, I send the request to save data through this Angular Ajax method:

```
save : function(screen_route, id=null) {

            var default_screen_route = screen_route;
            //var self = this;
            //params = $('#store_form').serializeArray();
            //console.log(params);

            var store_form = document.getElementById('store_form');
            form_data = new FormData(store_form);

            if (document.getElementById("id")== null)  
            {
                form_data.append('_method', "POST");
                var method = 'POST';
            } else {

                //---------- this line because $.ajax doesn't support PATCH method.
                form_data.append('_method', "PATCH");
                var method = 'POST';

                id = document.getElementById("id").value;
                screen_route = screen_route + '/' + id;
            }

            /*
            return $http({
                method: method,
                url: screen_route,
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : undefined },
                data: form_data,
            });
            */

            return $.ajax({
                type: method,
                url: screen_route,
                async: false,
                data: form_data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.success) {

                        //----- sweet alert plugin -----
                        swal({
                              title: '',
                              text: response.success,
                              type: "success",
                              timer: 3000,
                              showConfirmButton: false
                        });

                    }
                    if(response.error) {
                        swal({
                              title: '',
                              text: response.error,
                              type: "error",
                              showConfirmButton: false
                        });
                    }

                    var current_id = response.id;
                    $http.get(default_screen_route +'/' + current_id ).success(function(response){
                        $('#dv_content').html(response);
                        $("#dv_save_btns").hide();
                        $("#dv_show_btns").show();
                        $("#dv_pagination").hide();

                        $( "#lnk_show_btns_edit" ).attr( "row_id", current_id );
                    });


                },
                error: function (response) {
                    var obj = response.responseJSON;
                    if(obj.errors) {
                        var errors = obj.errors;
                    } else {
                        var errors = obj;
                    }
                    var errorsHtml = '<ul>';
                    $.each(errors, function (index, value) {
                        errorsHtml += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
                    });
                    errorsHtml += '</ul>';

                    swal({
                      title: '',
                      text: errorsHtml,
                      type: "error",
                      html: true
                    });

                 },
            });

        },
```

to validate the inputs, I always make a request class and rules function, but because I use the same Angular function to save, I make switch case to check the current request HTTP method, when it = `POST` this mean I insert record, when it = `PATCH`, this mean I update the record.

but in this case there is a strange mistake, this a rules function in Request class:

```
public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [];

        switch($this->method())
        {           
            case 'GET':
            case 'DELETE':
                {
                    print_r("1 \n");
                    $rules = [];
                }
            case 'POST':
                {
                    print_r("2 \n");
                    $rules = [
                        'email' => 'required|email|unique:technicians',
                        'mobile' => 'required|unique:technicians',
                        'name' => 'required',
                        'password' => 'required',
                        'id_number' => 'required|unique:technicians',
                        'image'       => 'required|max:2048|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg,gif',
                        'lat' => 'required',
                        'long' => 'required',
                    ];

                    if ($this->attributes->has('country_id') && $this->attributes['country_id']==9) {
                         $rules['id_number'] = 'required|unique:technicians|number|max:10|min:10';
                    }
                }
            case 'PUT':
            case 'PATCH':
                {
                    print_r("3 \n");
                    $rules = [
                        'email' => 'required|email',
                        'mobile' => 'required',
                        'name' => 'required',
                        //'password' => 'required',
                        'id_number' => 'required',
                        'lat' => 'required',
                        'long' => 'required',
                    ];
                }
            default:break;
        }

        print_r($this->method()." \n");
        print_r($rules);
        return $rules;

    }
```

it is supposed to print `2` and go to execute the `POST` case, but it is the output of the code:

```
2 
3 
POST 
Array
(
    [email] => required|email
    [mobile] => required
    [name] => required
    [id_number] => required
    [lat] => required
    [long] => required
)
```

it print 2, 3 really I don't know how? and of course it print the method `POST` and it is true, but it set `$rules` array with values when method = `PATCH`

What is the wrong here?

it is the request url:

> http://localhost/utf/fixbees/public/admin/technicians

and the request header:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/utf/fixbees/public/admin/technicians
Request Method:POST
Status Code:422 Unprocessable Entity
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:367
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 03 Apr 2017 12:09:21 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
phpdebugbar-id:a6b7cf5aa8f5117ed187b9fae77bedb2
Server:Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImFpdnJWM3Z2WmQyM3BlREJpVitXOUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicXJJSmcxVWZLeDhiT2Q4b1g1UStOWUpGbTQyQno1cHQwTmlsb05iWG9GUDlzU3FMcHZrVmg5bXpBaUQ3Zmkra3V1cENlXC9HZXhzSlloWjlGc2lraXJnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI3ODlkNzE0MGFjZjEzZmI2ZjNmYjg4ZWJlOTk4ZWNiNzIzZjdmY2MzN2UzZGNkZWM0NWJjYjVkNDU5NjQzNzI0In0%3D; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik55SUFyY0huTGJBXC82T2o1dHh5NXNBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InpLdkJXTVdoenFrbWVXMGtcL1plQ1czWGhmNnBIcDhGdDRKam0wMU53MXpvMmt0Z1A4QThlRkZXU2dUXC9Uc01CMGIxVDRuRjdzQWF6TDQ3RHVLeGh2aUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjAwMWVkMmM4ZjgzYWZjYTYzODM4ZjQzOGZiZWZjN2NhODhhNzBmMTcwYWI1NjhhNzU3OTIyOWIxZmE4MWRlMzYifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 03-Apr-2017 14:09:21 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.15
X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1357
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Cookie:intend=eyJpdiI6ImZRM2NSUmE5eXV3b0d2TUVzcW1LcWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiR0VjTmk2MUt2S29qTWV3c1dMSUZrdDJiOTgrZmdMRDdGaVwvSXpkYzNLbGdKV0hnSndmN2c2dzA5WUZsYjN4b1FoSkp0U2JYbUN6UGFLb1wveGdUS04xQT09IiwibWFjIjoiNDhkNDAxOTI4ZDY5MWEyMTE4OWE1MzIzOWNlMTIwNGQxYzU0NzQyNmJmYjUxODViNmQ5MDBmODVhZWJhZTQyMSJ9; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkY0QWRUc041QkhQaHpQRk5HWVwvb0pBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InV6UWZlczdBN0ZNazR3TUlvUkQ1MHFVc0M0d1ZaZ0pyTWI2V2txNzU2blZCaGowR1wvS25mUTJrNllIc1M5ajhsN0x1OGpHM1Z1UkpnQjVtcUZuYlIrQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMDkzNWRlZjAzYTllMmI1YzYzM2EzMGU4MDg5OTYxMTYzYjRhYjhhNzE4N2E0MjJhOWZmZGFjYjZhODczYmI4NyJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ijk0azNCaDRFSHFaRTF5K2VBYlhtMkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUExENHh0eVF0MTdoeHJNNVFIVUlGXC9RcjBTekUyZkRWeVF0MDN5S2F0eTI3QnJrODVvYzk3Sngrd1hEVU52RUNEV0dDWlpNWTlnblFldXJcLzZoM0hhUT09IiwibWFjIjoiODkzMzMzYzJkZjUwYmQ1MTJkOWM1YTEzM2ZjMzIxZmUzM2UxMGVmYzg2MDVmODA2YmQwY2Y3NDc1M2VhN2M5NyJ9
DNT:1
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/utf/fixbees/public/admin/technicians
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN:ovfFSeLUbkrQvSX1DYTN9HLuoNWhEEL2X2kJ69bo
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

ovfFSeLUbkrQvSX1DYTN9HLuoNWhEEL2X2kJ69bo
------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"


------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"


------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"


------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mobile"


------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id_number"


------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="country_id"

9
------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="city_id"

12
------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lat"


------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="long"


------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="active"

on
------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_method"

POST
------WebKitFormBoundaryzbqA326BcIu3Ciep--
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing the `break` statement , so your switch case will do -*in pseudo-code*- :-

check your first case `GET` ? not get , go to next case
`DELETE` ? not delete , go to the next case
`POST` ? yes, continue executing until your next `break` statement.

consider the following example:

```
$c = 'c';

switch ($c) {
    case 'a': echo 'a' . "\n";
    case 'b': echo 'b' . "\n";
    case 'c': echo 'c' . "\n";
    case 'd': echo 'd' . "\n";
    case 'e': echo 'e' . "\n";
}
```

the output will be as follows:

```
c
d
e
```

while this :

```
$c = 'c';

switch ($c) {
    case 'a': echo 'a' . "\n"; break;
    case 'b': echo 'b' . "\n"; break;
    case 'c': echo 'c' . "\n"; break;
    case 'd': echo 'd' . "\n"; break;
    case 'e': echo 'e' . "\n"; break;
}
```

will only print `c` ,

so to solve your issue you need to break your switch cases :

```
switch($this->method())
{
    case 'GET':
    case 'DELETE':
        {
            print_r("1 \n");
            $rules = [];
        }
        break;
    case 'POST':
        {
            print_r("2 \n");
            $rules = [
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:technicians',
                'mobile' => 'required|unique:technicians',
                'name' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
                'id_number' => 'required|unique:technicians',
                'image'       => 'required|max:2048|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg,gif',
                'lat' => 'required',
                'long' => 'required',
            ];

            if ($this->attributes->has('country_id') && $this->attributes['country_id']==9) {
                $rules['id_number'] = 'required|unique:technicians|number|max:10|min:10';
            }
        }
        break;
    case 'PUT': break;
    case 'PATCH':
        {
            print_r("3 \n");
            $rules = [
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'mobile' => 'required',
                'name' => 'required',
                //'password' => 'required',
                'id_number' => 'required',
                'lat' => 'required',
                'long' => 'required',
            ];
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```